# Bootstrap. The vertical alignment of a single column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertical align the furthest right column within my bootstrap panel. I know this question has been asked and responded to on stackoverflow, but all of the solutions I have found do not work, as they typically require all of the columns within the row to be centered.

[Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/wHZCrMCleg#)

My code:

```css
.hotel-panel {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.panel-image {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.rate {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body hotel-panel">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left panel-image">
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/governmentswagger/IMG_2843.JPG" alt="asdf" width="250">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <h4>Hilton Atlanta Buckhead</h4>
        <p>Free parking</p>
        <p>Free wifi</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 rate text-center">
        <h4>$289</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Govt Rate Link</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [panel with table](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.hotel-table td {
  padding: 16px !important;
}
.hotel-table h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
td.hotel-image {
  padding: 0 !important;
  width: 250px;
}
td.hotel-about {
  width: 100%;
}
td.hotel-rate {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table hotel-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="hotel-image">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/governmentswagger/IMG_2843.JPG" alt="asdf" width="250">
          </td>
          <td class="hotel-about">
            <h4>Hilton Atlanta Buckhead</h4>
            <p>Free parking</p>
            <p>Free wifi</p>
          </td>
          <td class="hotel-rate">
            <h4>$289</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Govt Rate Link</button>
          </td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/v8JrzAcONR

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox but this would impact the entire row. I think the simplest way is to use transform..

```
  .vcenter {
      top:50%;
      transform: translateY(50%);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  }
```

http://www.bootply.com/4dADRREDVH